# Reactify transform not running when declared in package.json

Tags: gulp, reactjs, browserify

I'm trying to use the reactify transform with browserify and gulp.

This gulp task works:

```
return browserify({
        paths: ['./node_modules','./app/scripts/'],
        entries: ['./app/scripts/index.js'],
        transform: ['reactify'],
        debug: true
    })
    .bundle()
    .pipe(source('bundle.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('.tmp/scripts/'));
```

If i remove the transform key from gulp and move it to package.json:

```
  "browserify": {
    "transform": [
      ["reactify", {"es6": true}]
    ]
  }
```

The transform no longer runs (also tried without es6).

I'm using this yeoman generator: https://www.npmjs.org/package/generator-react-spa

Can anyone please explain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The config in package.json is used in two situations:

- you use the browserify command line tool
- it's a package other than the current (e.g. react's package.json config is used when you require it)

If you're using the api, you manually specify transforms.  To avoid repeating yourself:

```
var package = require('./package.json');
browserify({
        paths: ['./node_modules','./app/scripts/'],
        entries: ['./app/scripts/index.js'],
        transform: package.browserify.transform,
        debug: true
})
```

or more generally this, where merge can be your favorite merge implementation (e.g. [_.defaults](http://underscorejs.org/#defaults))

```
browserify(merge({}, package.browserify.transform, {
        paths: ['./node_modules','./app/scripts/'],
        entries: ['./app/scripts/index.js'],
        debug: true
}))
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it is not supposed to work that way? I.e. browserify command doesn't read your own package.json, only the modules that are required (?).

https://github.com/substack/node-browserify#browserifytransform

> Now when somebody require()s your module, brfs will automatically be applied to the files in your module without explicit intervention by the person using your module.

Comment: The Reactify docs mention you "can configure it in package.json": https://github.com/andreypopp/reactify#es6-transformation