# Gulp + Browserify: CoffeeScript not loading when loading files from node_modules

Tags: coffeescript, gulp, browserify

After setting up the folder structure for my Gulp project, I was wondering how to do paths in browserify, and found this page: https://github.com/substack/browserify-handbook#organizing-modules. It recommends putting common application parts in a subfolder of `node_modules`. This appears to be working, it's getting the files, but it's not applying my `coffeeify` transform, so it's throwing errors because it's trying to interpret them as JS. Any ideas how to fix this? This is my browserify config:

```
browserify: {
  // Enable source maps
  debug: true,
  // Additional file extentions to make optional
  extensions: ['.coffee', '.hbs'],
  // A separate bundle will be generated for each
  // bundle config in the list below
  bundleConfigs: [{
    entries: src + '/javascript/app.coffee',
    dest: dest,
    outputName: 'app.js'
  }, {
    entries: src + '/javascript/head.coffee',
    dest: dest,
    outputName: 'head.js'
  }]
}
```

and these are the relevant bits form my `package.json`.

```
"browserify": {
  "transform": [
    "coffeeify",
    "hbsfy"
  ]
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26242601/reactify-transform-not-running-when-declared-in-package-json

Comment: Hey @Steven, there is a GitHub issue that may answer this: https://github.com/substack/node-browserify/issues/993#issuecomment-63225009.

It says that symlink-ed node_modules—say it’s called app— have to have a package.json with a "browserify" section similar to this: "browserify": { "transform": [ "coffeeify" ] }

Answer (score 1):

`Transfrom`s aren't applied to files in `node_modules` unless they are marked as being global: https://github.com/substack/node-browserify#btransformtr-opts.  If you choose to make it global, be warned, the documentation suggests against it:

> Use global transforms cautiously and sparingly, since most of the time
>   an ordinary transform will suffice.

You won't be able to specify the tranform in `package.json`:

> You can also not configure global transforms in a package.json like
>   you can with ordinary transforms.

The two options are programmatically, by passing `{global: true}` as options or at the command line with the `-g` option:

```
browserify -g coffeeify main.coffee > bundle.js
```